# How to stop sending the last received char of UART echo function?

Tags: avr, uart, isr, loop

I developed a code for uart based ISR with linear buffers, the problem is that it keep sending the last received char in Arduino IDE.

Here's the application code:

```
#include "uart_new.h"

void setup() {
uart_init_new(103);
DDRB = 0xff;
}

void loop() {
uint16_t c;
c = get_char();
if (c & NO_DATA)
{
  PORTB |= (1<<PB5);
  _delay_ms(500);
  PORTB &= ~(1<<PB5);
  _delay_ms(500);
}
else
{
  put_char(c);
}
}
```

The header file:

```
#ifndef uart_new_H_
#define uart_new_H_

#define NO_DATA     0x0100
#define Buf_OF      0x0200
#define FR_Er       0x0400
#define DOR_Er      0x0800
#define PARTY_Er    0x1000

#define buf_s 32
#define buf_mask Buf_s - 1
#define baud_rate 9600

void uart_init_new(uint16_t ubrr);
void put_char(uint8_t data);
uint16_t get_char(void);
void put_s(uint8_t *str);

#endif // uart_new_H_
```

The source code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "uart_new.h"

/*******************************************
If you want to prevent reading a string
backwards then you need FIFO implementation
*******************************************/

static volatile uint8_t rx_buf[32],tx_buf[32];
static volatile uint8_t rx_p,tx_p,rx_cnt,tx_cnt;
static volatile uint8_t rx_errors,tx_sBuf,rx_sBuf;

void uart_init_new(uint16_t ubrr)
{
    rx_p=0,tx_p=0,rx_cnt=0,tx_cnt=0;
    UBRR0H = (uint8_t)(ubrr>>8);
    UBRR0L = (uint8_t)ubrr;
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0)|(1<<RXCIE0); //Enable Rx and Tx & Receive interrupt
    UCSR0C = (1<<USBS0)|(3<<UCSZ00);            //Set frame format: 8data, 2stop bit
}

uint16_t get_char(void)
{
    if (rx_cnt == 0)
        return NO_DATA;
    else if (rx_p < rx_cnt)
        return rx_buf[rx_p++];
}

void put_char(uint8_t data)
{
    if (tx_cnt < 32)                        // start count the input data
        tx_buf[tx_cnt++] = data;            // 1st input location tx_cnt

        UCSR0B |= (1<<UDRIE0);
}

void put_s(uint8_t *str)
{
    while (*str)
        put_char(*str++);
}

ISR(USART_RX_vect)
{
    if (rx_cnt < 32)                        // start count the received data
        rx_buf[rx_cnt++]=UDR0;              // 1st output location rx_cnt
    else
        rx_cnt = 0;                         // when the counter reached max value, reset it, overwrite everything

if (!(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)))
        UCSR0B &= ~(1<<UDRIE0);
}
ISR(USART_UDRE_vect)
{
    uint8_t i;
    if (tx_p < tx_cnt)                      // check if pointer < counted data
        UDR0 = tx_buf[tx_p++];
        else
        {
            for (i=0;i<tx_cnt;i++)
                tx_buf[i]=0;
            tx_p = 0;                       // when the pointer reach max value, reset it
            tx_cnt= 0;                      // also reset counter for new transmission
            UCSR0B &= ~(1<<UDRIE0);         // disable empty data register interrupt
        }
}
```

If the there's a received char, then ISR is executed, the function exit the LED blink loop, but when the receive stops and there're no more data it doesn't return the blink state and keeps sending the last received char. How to solve this problem?

Comment: We cannot see the code inside your UART functions. You have to show us. Also: are you sure, that the buffer is emptied correctly? It seems as the last byte is not deleted after the read, hence getting read over and over again

Comment: Post updated, added the main source code.

Comment: How is the `NO_DATA` const defined?  Are you sure, that you have to use the bitwise `&` in the if statement? Shouldn't you check for equality with `==`? Please also include the corresponding header file

Comment: 1. The Arduino core library provides the `Serial` object, which is a perfectly good driver for the UART. Why would you want to replace it with your broken implementation? 2. If you really want to reimplement it, start by learning how a [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) works.

Comment: Well, I want to learn how to program microcontroller peripherals so I get more skills in programming, if I'm having problems now then it means I'm still at a low level in programming. I know Serial and I know other ready pre-written codes but I have to be good at programming core peripherals so I'm good to go with larger projects.

Comment: Post updated with header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, many problems with this code. The most fundamental flaw
is that it uses linear buffers, where you should be using [circular
buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) instead. I'll come to this later. Now, if we look
at the details, in the header file:

```c++
#define Buf_OF      0x0200
```

This, and a few other macros, serve no purpose. Do not put "TODO" items
in the code: put them in a TODO file, or as comments. Strive to always
have your code in a clean state. More so when you post it in a public
place.

```c++
#define buf_mask Buf_s - 1
```

This is presumably intended to be used as a bit mask, but it will not
work reliably. For example, if you try to complement the mask as
`~buf_mask`, the preprocessor will expand that to `~Buf_s - 1`, and the
compiler will interpret it as `(~Buf_s) - 1`, which is **not** what you
want. You should always parenthesize any expression you use in a macro,
as

```c++
#define buf_mask (Buf_s - 1)
```

Later,

```c++
void put_s(uint8_t *str);
```

If you want to be able to issue calls like `put_s("Hello!");`, then you
should declare the function as:

```c++
void put_s(const char *str);
```

Now, in the implementation, you have:

```c++
static volatile uint8_t rx_errors,tx_sBuf,rx_sBuf;
```

All those are unused. Remove them. Again, this is supposed to be a
program, not a TODO list.

Later,

```c++
uint16_t get_char(void)
{
    if (rx_cnt == 0)
        return NO_DATA;
    else if (rx_p < rx_cnt)
        return rx_buf[rx_p++];
}
```

The compiler should have warned you about this: what if both conditions
are false? In this case the function will return by reaching its end,
with no specified return value. This is undefined behavior. You should
probably return `NO_DATA` in this case. But then, that's what you should
return every time you are not returning valid data, so the function can
be simply written as:

```c++
uint16_t get_char(void)
{
    if (rx_p < rx_cnt)
        return rx_buf[rx_p++];
    else
        return NO_DATA;
}
```

Later, in `ISR(USART_RX_vect)`,

```c++
if (rx_cnt < 32)
    rx_buf[rx_cnt++]=UDR0;
else
    rx_cnt = 0;
```

If you set `rx_cnt` to zero without updating `rx_p`, then the subsequent
characters that you will put in the buffer will be ignored by
`get_char()` until you fill the buffer up to `rx_p`. Thus you presumably
want to set `rx_p` to zero also. And if you do this at the start if the
ISR, you ensure that *at least* the current character is not lost:

```c++
// when the counter reached max value, reset the buffer
if (rx_cnt >= 32) {
    rx_p = 0;
    rx_cnt = 0;
}
rx_buf[rx_cnt++]=UDR0;
```

Further in the ISR:

```c++
if (!(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)))
    UCSR0B &= ~(1<<UDRIE0);
```

This makes no sense: if you have no pending character in the *receive*
register (which you should not have, as you have just read that
register), then you disable the ISR that serves the *transmitter*. The
transmitter and the receiver should be able to work independently:
remove those lines.

Then, in `ISR(USART_UDRE_vect)`:

```c++
for (i=0;i<tx_cnt;i++)
    tx_buf[i]=0;
```

This serves no purpose. If you handle your buffers properly, you should
*never* access uninitialized data in them. Thus you will never read the
zeroes you are writing here. Again, remove those lines.

If you implement all the fixes above, you should end up with a code that
“kind of” works. There are still a couple of issues though:

**Race conditions**

If `get_char()` gets interrupted by `ISR(USART_RX_vect)`, you can get
what is known as a “race condition”, which can lead to incoherent
behavior or data corruption. For example, testing `rx_p<rx_cnt` is not
atomic: the CPU has to read `rx_cnt` from RAM, then read `rx_p`, then
compare them. If the interrupt fires between the two memory reads, the
ISR can set both values to zero, then the test will compare the old
`rx_cnt` with the new `rx_p` (which is now zero) and incorrectly assume
there is valid data to be returned.

There are other places where this can byte you. For example, `rx_p++` is
not atomic either, it's a read-modify-write sequence that can very well
be interrupted in the middle. And there are similar issues if
`put_char()` gets interrupted by `ISR(USART_UDRE_vect)`.

The fix for these issues is to disable interrupts while you are in the
“critical sections” that access data shared with the ISRs. This can be
done using `noInterrupts()`/`interrupts()` pairs or, if you prefer the
avr-libc style, with [atomically executed code blocks](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__atomic.html). For
example:

```c++
#include <util/atomic.h>

uint16_t get_char(void)
{
    uint16_t result = NO_DATA;
    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE) {
        if (rx_p < rx_cnt)
            result = rx_buf[rx_p++];
    }
    return result;
}
```

A similar protection is needed in `put_char()`.

**Linear buffers**

This is the main flaw, because it will require you to rethink a
significant part of your code. Imagine what can happen if the UART
transmitter lags slightly behind your program calling `put_char()`. Say
you reach `tx_p` = 30 and `tx_cnt` = 32. Then your
buffer has 30 “empty” cells (from 0 to 29 the space is available, as
that data has already been sent) and two cells with bytes pending to be
sent (at positions 30 and 31). If you call now `put_char()` to send an
extra byte, that byte will be lost (because `tx_cnt<32` is false). This
is unacceptable: you should not loose data when the buffer is almost
empty!

The solution is to put the extra byte at position 0, the next one at
position 1, etc. But this creates a complication: now the pending bytes
are at positions 30, 31, 0, 1... At this point your buffer becomes a
[circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). It's not a big deal, but you **must**
read about the subject before you try to implement it.

Note that the same issue applies to the receive buffer: both buffers
should be made circular.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations and declaring my mistakes, now I'm trying to improve the code with linear buffers until I get the code to work with very minimal errors, then I move to circular buffers. My question is that can linear buffers be very efficient as circular buffers?

Comment: Again, thank you very much, I actually tweaked the code little more this morning. I would like you to provide me with your opinion. But where should I post the new code?

Comment: Also, I want you to know that I want to do more testing on uart and I want to test my skills in C and how I can solve problems. I know that circular buffers are the best option for uart, but even so I'm trying to do the best code with linear buffers, then I move to circular buffers.